# Extracting matching rows from data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with 30+ columns. I want to extract the rows where three specific columns are matching with some reference values. Example, col A has state name, col B has site types, col C has number of annual visitors. I want to find out number of visitors (col C) going to capital (col B) of New Jersey (col A).

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
subset(my_df,A=="New Jersey" & B=="capitol")$C
```

or

```
with(my_df,my_df[A=="New Jersey" & B=="capitol","C"])
```

You should probably check out some introductory R material: e.g. http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/subset_R.htm ; http://digitheadslabnotebook.blogspot.ca/2009/07/select-operations-on-r-data-frames.html (results of googling "selection rows from a data frame")

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy with a subset command.

```
subset(data, A=="New Jersey" & B=="capital", select=C)
```

Or with standard indexing

```
data$C[ data$A=="New Jersey" & data$B=="capital" ]
```

I strongly recommend reading a [basic introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html) because this is pretty elementary stuff.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick - it is indeed pretty basic - I have started learning R only recently and was using && instead of & and hence was not getting anywhere for a few hours now.